# How can I access to member of QPointer in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qpointer

My project uses Qt and QML.

I want to bind a property that can be multiple types of a class.

For example:

```cpp
class base : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant myVar read myVar NOTIFY myVarChanged)
    QVariant myVar() {return var;}
    
signals:
    void myVarChanged();
private:
    QVariant var
}

class A : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
/* 
similar with upper class
*/
    QString myStr;
}

somewhere
{
    QPointer<A> mine = new A;
    base.myVar = QVariant::fromValue(mine)
}
```

Now I can have Base in QML.

When I call:

```qml
console.log(base.myVar)
```

console prints:

```cpp
QVariant(QPoitner<A>(/*address*/)
```

But I can't get further. I want to get `myStr` by using `base.myVar.myStr`, but it is undefined. How do I solve this?

I can't use `Q_GADGET` because `myStr` changes.

I have to put class B or C in `myVar` sometimes, not only class A, so I have to use QVariant.

Comment: Why not register class A so QML knows about it? Is this Qt5 or Qt6?

Comment: @JarMan It is Qt6.6. I am not sure what register means. All those classes are QObject so i thought QML must knows it. It worked with Q_GADGET without register something but as I mentioned I can't use Q_GADGET.

Comment: @sqa, these classes are not `QObject` they inherit from `QObject` like almost all `QML` classes.  you have to register them in the `QML` metasystem so it knows them (what is `myVar`, for example).

Comment: @folibis thank you for your comment. I googled about it and I found `qRegisterMetaType` and `qmlRegisterType`. I have no idea how to apply to my code. but I will research about it. Are those what you meant?

Comment: [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html) are the relevant docs. I think the easiest way would be to add `QML_ELEMENT` and `QML_UNCREATABLE` to your class definition.

Comment: I accidently solved the problem.
`base.myVar.myStr` doesn't work but
`property A a: base:myVar; a.myStr` works.
I still have no idea why those two are different but thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `QVariant::fromValue` and `qvariant_cast`.

If you want to cast to `QObject*` as an intermediate step, you can `dynamic_cast` before converting it to a `QVariant` on the way out, and, on the way back, you use `qvariant_cast` then `qobject_cast`.

```cpp
    YourObject* m_ptr;

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant getValue()
    {
        return toQVariant(m_ptr);
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE bool compare(const QVariant& other)
    {
        return comparePointers(m_ptr, fromQVariant(other));
    }

protected:
    static QVariant toQVariant(const YourObject* ptr)
    {
        // Direct Method: convert C++ YourObject* pointer to QVariant for QML
        return QVariant::fromValue<YourObject*>(ptr);

        // QObject Method: convert C++ YourObject* to a QObject* then to QVariant
        // return QVariant::fromValue<QObject*>(dynamic_cast<QObject*>(ptr));
    }

    QStatic YourObject* fromQVariant(const QVariant& variantValue)
    {
        // Direct Method: convert QVariant from QML to a C++ YourObject* ptr;
        return _other = qvariant_cast<YourObject*>(other);

        // QObject Method: convert QVariant to QObject to YourQObject.
        // QObject* qobj = qvariant_cast<QObject*>(other);
        // return qobject_cast<YourObject*>(qobj);
    }

    static bool comparePointers(YourObject* a, YourObject* b)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Another solution you may want to consider is using `QJSValue`. `QJSValue QJSEngine::newQObject(QObject* object)` basically creates a JavaScript object that wraps the given QObject with JavaScriptOwnership. i.e. the QML Engine's garbage collector will take care of cleanup of the object when it goes out of scope. You usually use this approach if you are newing to your QObject, but, you want QML Engine to take care of the remainder of the object life-cycle. If you were to receive a `QJSValue` from QML, you will have to call `QString QJSValue::toObject()` to recover the QObject and then you will have to do a `qobject_cast`.

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvariant.html#fromValue
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#qobject_cast
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvariant.html#qvariant_cast
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsengine.html#newQObject
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsvalue.html#toQObject